# New to testing, how would I test this method with Mocha, Chai, Enzyme, and Sinon?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Here's my method

```
  handleKeyEvent(event) {
    const code = event.keyCode;

    if (UsedKeys.includes(code)) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (code === KeyCodes.DOWN) {
        this.modifyIndexBy(1);
      } else if (code === KeyCodes.UP) {
        this.modifyIndexBy(-1);
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm still pretty new to testing, and I have no idea how I'd go about testing this piece. 
The method takes an event, so do I have to synthesize an event object and pass it in?

After that, do I just somehow test that `this.modifyIndexBy()` gets called?

This method doesn't return anything. Do I modify my code to be more testable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

- You could create the object, and then spy on `modifyRowIndexBy` to check that it is called when `handleKeyDown` is called with the given parameter.
- You could separate your key handling from your "index modifying" so that they can be tested independently (it is bad practice to spy on the same object that you are testing)
- What does `modifyIndexBy` actually **do**? You could test that the *outcome* is the same (so it doesn't actually test that `modifyIndexBy` is called, but that what `modifyIndexBy` should do is done). This is a more [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124048/discussion-between-james-monger-and-brandon-sturgeon).